# SQL LIKE different output when using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Hello today I have practiced SQL statements. When I was trying to select from database with %like% it outputted different values when I was using variable and when I wasn't using it.

See follorwing
Consider simple table called POSTS each post has CONTENT and HEADING

[image: Post]

Now when I try to select from this table with

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts
WHERE Headline like '%'+'fun'+'%' OR Content like '%'+'fun'+'%'
```

I get following output :

[image: output]

However if I try to select using variable in the search as:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR = 'fun'
SELECT * FROM Posts
WHERE Headline like '%'+@test+'%' OR Content like '%'+@test+'%'
```

I get this output:

[image: output2]

So I wonder how come this variable changes results when in theory it has to have same ouput?

Comment: Here is a great article on this topic. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your declaration:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR = 'fun'
```

Afterwards, `@test` has the value `'f'`.  Why?  It has only one character.

*Always* put a length in when using string declarations in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(255) = 'fun'
```